# How create table and change the user owner

Tags: sas

I create, using SAS Guide, one table, but when i try to insert data into the table, i don't have permission. I see the user owner it's different than user who create table.

I create table using this code:

```
data test.teste;
format idRegistro 4.;
informat idRegistro 4.;
stop;
run;
```

The user owner should be may user for example test but I see the owner it's the root user.

Can I change the owner user when execute this data procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I change the permition instead of the owner.

After create table you can use one of the options below:

```
data _null_;
 call system("chmod 777 /test/teste.sas7bdat");
run;
```

OR

```
x chmod 777 /test/teste.sas7bdat;
```

Thanks